# Multiple writable mappings in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, pojo

I would like to make a review about some user at my system, this review is made by others users. So here it's my user's table:

[image: user table]

And this is my user_review table:

[image: user review table]

The EclipseLink is generating like this (actually it insted of `@PrimaryJoinColumn` was `@JoinColumn` it change it because of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952115/multiple-writable-mappings-exception-in-eclipselink) ):

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    private String review;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
//  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_user_reviewer")
    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user_reviewer")
    private User reviewer;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
//  @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
    @ManyToOne 
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_user")
    private User user;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserInfo
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
    private UserInfo userInfo;
```

And keeps giving me this error:

```
Join column "user_id" cannot be resolved on table "user_review"
```

I really don't what to do 'cause I already try many things, different associations but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm - your summary:

*Multiple writable mappings in JPA?*

does not match what seems to be your question:

Why do I get this error: Join column "user_id" cannot be resolved on table "user_review"?

So I'm guessing you experience the "multiple writable..." problem when you specify a `@JoinColumn` on your `user` field; and you get the "...cannot be resolved..." problem when you specify a `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` on your `user` field.

`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` cannot be used on a `@ManyToOne` mapping. (It can be used on a `@OneToOne` mapping when entities share a primary key.) As a result, Eclipse is calculating the default join column name as defined by the JPA spec (which is `"user_id"`), and since that column is not on your `user_review` table, you get an error message indicating the field cannot be resolved on the database table.

You should un-comment the `@JoinColumn` on your `user` field. That results in two `@OneToMany` mappings that will determine the foreign key to be written to the `id_user` column on the database - it will take the value of the primary key of either the `User` referenced by the `user` field or the `UserInfo` referenced by the `userInfo` field. This is not allowed. Either you need to rework your database relations or your object model or mark one of the mappings read-only (`@JoinColumn(name="id_user", insertable = false, updatable = false)`).

Answer (score 1):

This would be the most strange thing .. but I just delete the line:

```
//  @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
```

And Eclipse do not alarm anymore about.. (so far =] )
I will leave this thread open 'cause I really think this is very strange to happen and solve like this.

**UPDATE**

I did as Brian instructed and it seems to solve my problem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_review")
public class UserReview implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    private String review;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user_reviewer", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user1;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user")
    private User user2;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to UserInfo
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private UserInfo userInfo;
        .. more code
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there is a mismatch between the code and the error message you posted.
The error message is complaining about a column named 'user_id', in your code however the @JoinColumn annotations uses 'id_user'.

That doesn't seem right, could it be that you copied the exception at one point and then changed the code?

Comment: It could be Doron, but I'm almost sure that I copied everything correctly. But soon I get near of the code, I will look into it.