# Why will foreign key data will not persist to mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa-2.0

I am working with a basic mySQL relational database using java. I have attached the entity classes for two tables that have a 1:M relationship. I have defined the 1 is to many and many is to 1 relationships in the entity tables. In the Projects class, I wanted to declare the foreign key (private int contractor_id) along with getters and setters (as shown commented out), but I kept getting a compile error stating the following *Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [projects.contractor_id].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.* I therefore commented them out as their value is set already in the BusinessAccount class. The data is now persisting to the database using the 'addProject()' method I have shown. However, the field contractor_id (ie the foreign key) is being passed as null to the Projects table. I have a value for contractor_id for the session (named sessionContractorId) but I am unable to pass it to the database as I have no setter for this table. Any suggestions would be appreciated on how to persist the value for the foreign key to the database?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_accounts")
public class BusinessAccount {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "businessAccount", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Projects> projects;



public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public List<Projects> getProjects()
{
    if (projects == null)
    {
        projects = new ArrayList<Projects>();
    }

    return projects;
}

public void setProjects(List<Projects> projects)
{
    this.projects = projects;
}

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Projects {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int project_id;

@Column(name = "project_name")
private String projectName;

@Column(name = "project_description")
private String projectDescription;

//@Column(name = "contractor_id")
//private int contractorId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "contractor_id", referencedColumnName="id") })
private BusinessAccount businessAccount;


public BusinessAccount getBusinessAccount() {
    if (businessAccount == null) {
        businessAccount = new BusinessAccount();
    }
    return businessAccount;
}

public void setBusinessAccount(BusinessAccount businessAccount) {
    this.businessAccount = businessAccount;
}

public int getProject_id() {
    return project_id;
}

public void setProject_id(int project_id) {
    this.project_id = project_id;
}

public String getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}

public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
}

public String getProjectDescription() {
    return projectDescription;
}

public void setProjectDescription(String projectDescription) {
    this.projectDescription = projectDescription;
}

//public int getContractorId() {
    //return contractorId;
//}

//public void setContractorId(int contractorId) {
    //this.contractorId = contractorId;
//}

}



@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProjectBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2107387060867715013L;
private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "NeedABuilderUnit";
private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

private Projects projects;


private List<BusinessAccount> businessAccount;

public ProjectBean() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

    List<BusinessAccount> businessAccount = em.createQuery("from BusinessAccount a", BusinessAccount.class)
            .getResultList();
    em.close();
    setBusinessAccount(businessAccount);
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    projects = new Projects();
}

public String addProject() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        String sessionEmail=Util.getEmail();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.email=:email");
        myQuery.setParameter("email", sessionEmail);
        List<BusinessAccount> accounts=myQuery.getResultList();
        int sessionContractorId=accounts.get(0).getId();
        em.persist(projects);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: Where does `projects` come from in the `addProject` method?

Comment: apologies-i was trying to cut down on the amount of code I was posting and missed that with projects origin not being shown. I have updated the code now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I notice about the code.

First, the code should work with entities and ignore the `id` fields for the particular entities.  So when you fetch the account, it should grab the entity instead of the id:

```
//Don't do this
List<BusinessAccount> accounts=myQuery.getResultList();
int sessionContractorId=accounts.get(0).getId();

//Instead do this
List<BusinessAccount> accounts=myQuery.getResultList();
BusinessAccount account =accounts.get(0); //hopefully an account exists
```

Second, in JPA you are responsible for managing both sides of an association.  So you must add the `Account` to the `Project` and on the other side of the relationship set the `Project` for the `Account`.  I never see this occur in the code, I only see the `projects` (not sure of its origin) being persisted.  Assuming `projects` is a `List<Project>` it would look something like this:

```
public String addProject() {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        String sessionEmail=Util.getEmail();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.email=:email");
        myQuery.setParameter("email", sessionEmail);
        List<BusinessAccount> accounts=myQuery.getResultList();
        BusinessAccount account =accounts.get(0);

        projects.setBusinessAccount(account); //managing both sides
        account.getProjects().add(projects); //managing both sides
        em.persist(projects);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        return "success";
    }
```

On a side note, you may want to change the class name to `Project` and use the variable name `project` since it more accurately depicts the relationship.  Also since you are creating a new `Project` you will need to instantiate the `List<BusinessAccount>`:

```
List<BusinessAccount> projects = new ArrayList<BusinessAccount>();
```

Hopefully this will solve your issues, I would recommend watching a this [video tutorial](http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/8) I created on Bidirectional One To Many Relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@JoinColumn(name="id_user", insertable = false, updatable = false)`

Please refer: [Multiple writable mappings in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245481/multiple-writable-mappings-in-jpa)

Hope this helps :)